# Using LocalDateTime with @Version annotation in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, java-8

I have the following fields in my `Entity` class:

```
@Version
@Column(name = "updated")
private LocalDateTime lastUpdated;

@Column(name = "created")
private LocalDateTime created;
```

The `created` field works fine, because I implemented an `AttributeConverter` from `LocalDateTime` to `Timestamp`.

The `lastUpdated` field gives the following error when deploying to the container:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterTypeAdapter cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType
```

I know this can be solved by using the `Timestamp` as the variable type of `lastUpdated` instead of `LocalDateTime`.

I want to know if I can override the `@Version` annotation behavior to accept the `LocalDateTime` as a variable type.

Comment: I don't think we can use version annotation on LocalDateTime . Supported data type for annotation  version field are int, Integer, short, Short, long, Long, java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: Yes I know. The question is if that behavior of the `@Version` annotation is overridable so it will accept `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: did you try with dependency `hibernate-java8` ? Below from hibernate doc `Support for using Java8 specific data-types such as any of the JSR 310 Date/Time types in domain model`

Comment: No, I was not aware of that library. Will surely try that.

Comment: What is the use case? It is a private field. Can't you just use Timestamp and expose it to clients of this class via public LocalDateTime getlastUpdated(){return timeStamp.toLocalDateTime()};

Comment: Do you know where I can find the documentation for that library?

Comment: @AlanHay Yes I could do that. I prefer however to expose just the Java 8 time api on my entities. I agree that I could do it on the getter. It's not a very practical problem. Just wondering if it can be done.

Comment: @Martijn Burger didn't get documentation, you can download source code, document from maven, checked source code it seems has support for Instant in Version annotation, check and let me know if this works for you, Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Martijn Burger, tried this and it worked, updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `hibernate-java8` dependency which is to support java 8 specific data types.

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Below from hibernate website

**Support for using Java8 specific data-types such as any of the JSR 310 Date/Time types in domain model.**

`VersionType<Instant>` is added as part of this, so you could use this for your requirement

**UPDATE 1**

Checked Version annotation on `LocalDateTime` with `hibernate-java8` dependency on H2 DB, it worked

Comment: Updated answer with test result